# MySQL Order Sorting based on particular order

Tags: mysql

I have a table

> galleries(id, name, file, ...)

the view is a slideshow of the photos. But its order depends on the id of the photo clicked from the album view.

Lets say the User clicks 4 out of the 10 records

then i want to sort the order as

```
4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, ...
```

or any order but keeping 4 at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL specially you can do

```
select * from galleries
order by id <> $clickedNumber,
         id
```

or generally in ANSI SQL

```
select * from galleries
order by case when id = $clickedNumber then 1 else 2 end,
         id
```

Comment: `<>` is the opposite of `=` and means *Is not equal to*. And it returns either `1` or `0` for true and false. You can sort by this result since it is a number.

Comment: but i want the ID result as well

Comment: What do you mean by that? The query sorts by 2 things to get 4 first and the rest in order.

Comment: let me check it out how to achieve this in cakephp